# Java - проблема с парсингом строки содержащей дату

Tags: java, дата, парсер

Люди помогите решить задачу:
Есть строка содержащая дату: "Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 MSK 2017", из этой строки мне нужно получить дату:

```
    String string = "Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 MSK 2017";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(string);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Date: " + date);
```

Ошибка собственно здесь: "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"

Comment: А в чем ошибка то? Какой-то эксепшен?

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat Apr 01 00:00:00 MSK 2017"

Comment: public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException
      {
        ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
        Date result = parse(source, pos);
        if (pos.index == 0)
            throw new ParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + source + 
    "\"" ,
                pos.errorIndex);
        return result;
    }

Answer (score 0):

z -> zzz

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 MSK 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Локаль забыл указать и zzz:
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",Locale.US);
Спасибо)